# Graphs report generated by tsung 1.5.0a not showing numbers on x/y axis

Tags: tsung

I download the tsung from github and compiled it, then do my common test tasks, but the graphs report cannot show numbers on x and y axis.

Do I miss something to upgrade from 1.4.2 to 1.5.0a?

Comment: As it's an Alpha version I suggest you to use either mailing list or the bug tracker for tsung to report the bug: https://support.process-one.net/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa or http://lists.process-one.net/pipermail/tsung-users/